# Android: Providing a mocked implementation during testing of a class using an interface

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, factory

I have an interface

```
public interface Example{

public int sum(int a, int b);

public int diff(int a, int b);

}
```

Now I have an implementation for this Interface:

```
public RealMath implements Example{

public int sum(int a, int b){
    //contact server do stuff and return value.
    return val;
}

public int diff(int a, int b){
    //contact server do stuff and return value.
    return val;
}
}
```

And there is a factory to provide the respective implementation:

```
public class ExampleFactory(){
public static final Example getExampleIns(String val){
return new RealMath();
}
}
```

Now, I have a class `User.java` which uses this `Example` Interface for some work. 
I want to test `User` in which there is a method which calls:

```
Example ex = ExampleFactory.getExampleIns();
ex.sum(val1, val2);
```

And based on this value it does some processing.

I want to unit test my code and would like to have a mocked implementation of Example interface, so that server dependency is not required and I just return some mocked values for the methods in the interface.

My thought is to provide my mocked implementation when `ExampleFactory.getExampleIns();` is called (when the test case is running).

I tired Mockito (Android) and that does not support static method mocking.

So I have two questions:
1. What is wrong with the above design where I have a factory and various implementations and return the suitable object based on requirements?

2. How do I test `User.java` by providing my mocked implementation for `Example` interface?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. What is wrong with the above design where I have a factory and various implementations and return the suitable object based on
>      requirements?

The implementation that you deliver in the factory is **hardcoded**, so, if you want to change the implementation, you have to change the code. You have no way to dynamically change the impl.

> 2.- How do I test User.java by providing my mocked implementation for Example interface?

Instead of using a factory, use Dependency Injection. You can pass the proper implementation of `Example` to your `User` in the constructor (for example), and store it as an instance variable, so that you can use it afterwards:

```
private Example exampleImpl;

public User(Example exampleImpl) {
    this.exampleImpl = exampleImpl;
}

public void methodUsingExample(Integer val1, Integer val2) {
    exampleImpl.sum(val1, val2);
}
```

When testing, you construct your `User` instance with the `Example` mock:

```
Example mockExample = mock(Example.class);
User user = new User(mockExample);
// now User is using your mock
user.methodUsingExample(1, 2);
```